# How to search specific phrase in all files in folder?

Tags: search, console

I'm a web dev and sometimes I have a very difficult time to find specific line in code.

Is there any possibility on Mac to search for specific text for exp. "1234567890" in any files included in specific folder?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work on a mac.

**Search for a string in a single file:**

```
cat ./file_name | grep "string"
```

**Search for a string in all files in a single directory**

```
grep "string" *
```

**Search for a string in all files in a directory (and sub-directories):**

```
grep -r "string"
```

Also, if you're using an IDE, most of them have built in support for that type of search.

Comment: Isn't `cat <file> | grep <pattern>` same as `grep <pattern> <file>`, but with less piping?

Comment: Maybe, just throwing out multiple ways to do things, and in a way it is more explicit for people learning command line tools.